# How to manipulate low level usb as raw electric signal?

Tags: linux, usb

By example, connecting the usb plug to computer and from driver or software send the energy pulsation manually without interpreter module. I need make a electronic function generator but from usb using pc cpu + software without a raspberry or dac, for use directely the cpu stable frecuency.

How to manipulate usb voltage pulsations manually from linux?

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

The USB lines are completely controlled by the firmware on the USB controller, and will always obey the USB protocol.

If you want an analog (or even digital) electronic function generator on a PC, try the sound line out connectors. Many motherboards support 6 channels at 96 kHz or so out of the box, with all the software infrastructure already in place. Add electronics to amplify as needed.

I don't understand what you mean by "for use directly the CPU stable frequency".

Comment: But, the sound card works maximum 96khz not mhz https://superuser.com/questions/238278/what-are-usual-maximum-output-frequencies-on-computer-sound-cards , usb works on 48mhz

Comment: Corrected. And no matter what speed USB works on (USB3 speeds are a lot higher), it is no use to you if you cannot control it ...